# Error ""tmp.txt" was unexpected at this time"

Tags: loops, variables, batch-file

I am still pretty new to batch and im running into this issue that i cannot seem to solve. When I run my script it returns "6766.txt" was unexpected at this time.My script is supposed to search for "store_versions" in a file called Local State. If it finds that line it it will be appended to a Temp file and then trim the line in a loop so that i only get A specific part of the output of the find command. The output of the command is **[319]  "store_versions": {** . And all I want is 319. Does anyone know what is causing this issue? 
Thanks,

```
    @echo off 
    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
    set tempfile="%random%.txt" 
    set LineNumFin=%LineNumFin%
    pause 
    Find /N "store_versions" < "Local State" > %tempfile% 

    for /f "tokens=1 delims=[]" %%a in %tempfile% do ( set LineNum=%%a

    pause
    )

    del "%tempfile%"
    echo Line Num: %LineNum%

    set /a result=%LineNum%+4

    echo %result%
```

Comment: Do a Google Search for the phrase, "was unexpected at this time", including the quotes.  Read some of the articles you find there, and adjust your troubleshooting accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `in` clause of the `for` command needs parenthesis

```
for /f "... options ..." %%a in ( file ) do ....
                                ^      ^
                                ^ here ^
```

And, as you are including quotes in the name of the file, you will need to include `usebackq` in the `options` part of the `for` command

Or, you can avoid the temporary file

```
for /f "tokens=1 delims=[]" %%a in (
    ' find /n "store_versions" ^< "Local State" '
) do set "lineNum=%%a"
```

The `for` command will execute the command, tokenize the records and retrieve the value.